# How to build bookshelf.js relationships once the model defined?

Tags: orm, relationship, bookshelf.js

I defined a Bookshelf model as

```
var Country =  Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'countries',
});

var Address =  Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'addresses',
    country: function() {
        return this.belongsTo(Country,'country_id');
    },
});
```

Now I can fetch one of my models from the database

```
new Country({name:"Italy"}).fetch()
.then(function(country){
```

And create and Address

```
    new Address({...}).save().then(function(address){
```

But I can't find, in the documentation, what method would help me to build the 'belongsTo' relationship. without manually setting the country_id attribute to the right one.

The only thing I see to build a relationship is the collection.create(object) method (http://bookshelfjs.org/#Collection-create) that is described as a convenience to create a model from an object,saving it, and adding it to the collection; I wouldn't know how to do the last part either.

Anyway, collection.create seems not to be available for model.related('collectionName') when collectionName refers to hasOne or belongsTo relationships since they do not reprensent collections.

Answer (score 7):

With the way you're doing it, you'd need to do it manually. You should be using the inverse relation like this:

```
var Country =  Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'countries',
    addresses: function() {
       return this.hasMany(Address);
    }
});

var Address =  Bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'addresses',
    country: function() {
        return this.belongsTo(Country,'country_id');
    },
});
```

Then you should be able to do:

```
new Country({name: Italy}).fetch().then(function(italy) {

   // also could be italy.related('addresses'), that would add
   // the addresses collection to the "italy" model's "relations" hash
   return italy.addresses().create({...});

}).then(function(address) {

   // ... saved to the db with the correct address

});
```

Comment: What if I want to add an existing model to the relationship?  Like italy.addresses().insert({...})  Edit: nevermind you would use attach

Comment: You only appear to be able to use `attach` on `belongsToMany` relationships.  I don't believe you'll be able to do `italy.addresses().attach(...)`.  As far as I can tell, you have to establish this relationship manually by setting the ID yourself if you're not doing it at create time, though the documentation is a bit lacking in this area.  There's a related [bug here](https://github.com/tgriesser/bookshelf/issues/71)

Comment: @tgriesser: If you're suggesting using the inverse, wouldn't you get a circular require error if you have them in two separate files?